# Terraform and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Guys I want to automate terraform with Jenkins pipeline
And My terraform is installed on different Vm and Jenkins 
Also. 
I know there is the Terraform Plugin. But it seems like The Terraform
Has to be installed on the same vm as Jenkins(or on /var/lib/jenkins/workspace) 
Is there anyway to get this done? 
Please share your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it's a good idea to keep your Jenkins machine as clean as possible, therefore you should avoid installing extra packages on it like Terraform. A better approach for this problem would be creating a Dockerfile with your Terraform binary and all the plugins that you need already built-in, then all you need to do in your Jenkins pipeline is build and execute your Terraform docker.

This is an example of such Dockerfile:

```
FROM hashicorp/terraform:0.11.7
RUN apk add --no-cache bash python3 && \
    pip3 install --no-cache-dir awscli

RUN mkdir -p /plugins

# AWS provider
ENV AWS_VERSION=1.16.0
ENV AWS_SHA256SUM=1150a4095f18d02258d1d52e176b0d291274dee3b3f5511a9bc265a0ef65a948

RUN wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-aws/${AWS_VERSION}/terraform-provider-aws_${AWS_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip && \
    echo "${AWS_SHA256SUM}  terraform-provider-aws_${AWS_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip" | sha256sum -c - && \
    unzip *.zip && \
    rm -f *.zip && \
    mv -v terraform-provider-aws_* /plugins/

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT []
```

The Terraform documentation also contains a section on best practices running Terraform in CI:
https://www.terraform.io/guides/running-terraform-in-automation.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the fastest way to have it done is use master/slave setup for you jenkins. So, what you need to do is to add slave to the machine on which your terraform is running.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a `Global Shared Library` [awesome-jenkins-utils](https://github.com/yogeshlonkar/awesome-jenkins-utils/wiki#terraform) with which you can use different version of terraform simultaneously in same pipeline. Additionally you can easily map build parameters to terraform variables